# How to find CSS/SCSS classes that contains single property

Tags: node.js, parsing, sass, abstract-syntax-tree, scss-lint

I have bunch of SCSS files. I'd like to find blocks which contains only single property, like:

```
&__input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

What tools may be helpful here (for example some NodeJS library etc.) ?

I've created repository to better show what I want to achieve:
https://github.com/lusarz/singular-scss-block-finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create an [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for each SCSS file, which will allow you to traverse and analyze your code.

The library [scss-parser](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/scss-parser) looks pretty robust for creating ASTs for SCSS, though I have never used it.

Comment: Thank you! I've started with scss-parser but stuck in this place:
https://github.com/lusarz/singular-scss-block-finder/blob/141c0f99c09a37453a0e1f88e595c244bd8542bd/lib/utils/SCSSUtils.js#L9

Comment: What part are you stuck with? How to traverse the AST? Also, please accept this answer when you are ready!

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to traverse AST, but it's up to me, I need to learn it :) Thanks for response, unfortunately I cannot accept this answer because my reputation on stackoverflow is too low.

Comment: Ok, good luck :) You might not have the reputation to vote up / down, but you should have the ability to "accept" the answer if you click the checkmark underneath the bottom arrow